# Is there a docker image with GitHub CLI Preinstalled?

Tags: docker, github

I can't find any docker image with gh tools (git hub client) preinstalled. Do yo know anyone?

Comment: you can create one :-)

Comment: Have you tried the Dockerfile from this GH issue? https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/658#issuecomment-701375745

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally I built my own image following the official docs for installation in ubuntu, since neither of the options provided worked:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt update && apt install -y \
  curl \
  gpg
RUN curl -fsSL https://cli.github.com/packages/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg | gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg;
RUN echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg] https://cli.github.com/packages stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/github-cli.list > /dev/null;
RUN apt update && apt install -y gh;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is

Can use this one here: https://hub.docker.com/r/maniator/gh

Answer (score -4):

yes. This one for example based on alpine: https://hub.docker.com/r/alpine/git
but it's a lot easier to create your own image or container and simply add git on build.
Here's an easy example Dockerfile to do that:

```
FROM nginx:latest

EXPOSE 3000
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git-all
ENTRYPOINT ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

Edit: obviously it should be "apt-get install -y git-all" instead of "apt-get install -y git" in that case. my bad.

Comment: I think OP is asking about the github tools, not git. https://github.com/cli/cli

Comment: Hi @GabeRAMturn This is git command not github cli (gh)

Comment: Yes, that's @Hans Kilian

Comment: @GabeRAMturn Are you sure git-all installs gh client?